# e.preventDefault() не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему не работает отмена события `e.preventDefault()`

```js
$("#text").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 188) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("введена запятая, а не должна");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: События ввода срабатывают по последовательности `keydown → keyup → input`, причем последние два - когда символ УЖЕ введен. Отменить нужно на keydown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyup` - уже поздно отменять.

```js
$("#text").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 188) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("введена запятая, а не должна");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```